# Oracle Professional Developer, Ver. 6.0.33 for MS-DOS

Tags: oracle, dos

I'm trying to install this fossil in DOS 6.22, which is running in Microsoft Virtual PC 2007. I'm hoping that some of you veteran Oracle developers have any recollection of in what order do these diskette images need to be loaded, since I don't have any documentation available for 6.0.33.

A friend emailed me the following 720K diskette images:

INSTALLE.IMG
RDBMS1.IMG
RDBMS2.IMG
RDBMS3.IMG
RSF.IMG
SQLLDR1.IMG
SQLLDR2.IMG
UTIL1.IMG
UTIL2.IMG
UTIL3.IMG

Within Virtual PC, I capture a diskette image, one at a time, into Drive A:
VPC's floppy disk emulation supports FAT12, so the supported diskette formats can be: 720K or 1.44MB. If anyone happens to have documentation for this legacy version, I would greatly appreciate a copy of it!

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6.0.33 on *DOS*???  I think you'll be very lucky.  In those days most Oracle installs were on some flavour  of Unix, or else VAX.

I see you have cross-posted to a couple of other sites, but you should post to specialist Oracle forums.  I recommend you try [OraFAQ site](http://www.orafaq.com/) and the [Oracle-L listserver](http://www.freelists.org/list/oracle-l), as a lot of old timers hang around both of them.

In the meantime, if I were a gambling man I would suggest that the order you show there is  very likely the correct order.  It would certainly be logical to start with an Install, then the main database.  After that the order of Utilities, Required Support Files and SQL Loader is a little less obvious, but perhaps RSF, Utils and then SQLLDR?  Have you tried them yet?  Perhaps each disk finishes by telling you want comes next?